# python removing whitespace from string in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists. I want to remove the leading and trailing spaces from them. The `strip()` method returns a copy of the string without leading and trailing spaces. Calling that method alone does not make the change. With this implementation, I am getting an `'array index out of bounds error'`. It seems to me like there would be "an x" for exactly every list within the list (0-len(networks)-1) and "a y" for every string within those lists (0-len(networks[x]) aka i and j should map exactly to legal, indexes and not go out of bounds?

```
i = 0
j = 0
for x in networks:
    for y in x:
    networks[i][j] = y.strip()
        j = j + 1
     i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're forgetting to reset `j` to zero after iterating through the first list.

Which is one reason why you usually don't use explicit iteration in Python - let Python handle the iterating for you:

```
>>> networks = [["  kjhk  ", "kjhk  "], ["kjhkj   ", "   jkh"]]
>>> result = [[s.strip() for s in inner] for inner in networks]
>>> result
[['kjhk', 'kjhk'], ['kjhkj', 'jkh']]
```

Comment: This is a good solution, since it doesn't mutate neworks, rather it creates a new list.

Comment: @hayden sometimes you don't want a new list and want to process already existing list

Comment: @AnuragUniyal I agree, especially if the list is very large... I'd still argue it's cleaner if it has a new name.

Comment: This solution works for me, so do several others, lot of good feedback thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This generates a new list:

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b ', ' c  ']
>>> map(str.strip, x)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```

Edit: No need to import `string` when you use the built-in type (`str`) instead.

Comment: Do you possibly mean `str.strip` - the `string` module has (apart from constants and a couple of helper functions) been deprecated for that purpose

Comment: thanks a lot!
    for x in tmp_networks:
        networks.append(map(string.strip, x))

Comment: But it is easy to use to do the operation in place:  `x[:] = map(str.strip,x)`.  Also note that you don't need to `import string` for this.  You could just do `str.strip`

Comment: string module appears to be still current
http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

Comment: @mgilson doesn't that create a new list in memory aswell and then assigns each value to the old one?

Comment: @Fabian -- In cpython2.x yes (in 3.0, map returns an iterator).  Other python implementations (e.g. pypy) *might* be able to JIT that extra work away.  But as far as a python user is concerned, **that doesn't really matter** (unless they run out of memory I suppose ...).  The important thing is that `x` and all other references to that list reflect the change whereas if you do `x = map(...,x)`, the other references to `x` won't see the change.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to count `i, j` yourself, just enumerate, also looks like you do not increment `i`, as it is out of loop and `j` is not in inner most loop, that is why you have an error

```
for x in networks:
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        x[i] = y.strip()
```

Also note you don't need to access networks but accessing 'x' and replacing value would work, as x already points to `networks[index]`

Answer (score 3):

So you have something like: `[['a ', 'b', ' c'], ['  d', 'e  ']]`, and you want to generate `[['a', 'b',' c'], ['d', 'e']]`. You could do:

```
mylist = [['a ', 'b', ' c'], ['  d', 'e  ']]
mylist = [[x.strip() for x in y] for y in mylist]
```

The use of indexes with lists is generally not necessary, and changing a list while iterating though it can have multiple bad side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
c=[]
for i in networks:
    d=[]
    for v in i:
         d.append(v.strip())
    c.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner version of cleaning list could be implemented using recursion. This will allow you to have a infinite amount of list inside of list all while keeping a very low complexity to your code.

Side note: This also puts in place safety checks to avoid data type issues with strip. This allows your list to contain ints, floats, and much more.

```
    def clean_list(list_item):
        if isinstance(list_item, list):
            for index in range(len(list_item)):
                if isinstance(list_item[index], list):
                    list_item[index] = clean_list(list_item[index])
                if not isinstance(list_item[index], (int, tuple, float, list)):
                    list_item[index] = list_item[index].strip()

        return list_item
```

Then just call the function with your list. All of the values will be cleaned inside of the list of list.

clean_list(networks)